# Jolt Transformation Nested Json to Flat Json

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am very close with this one. But, am afraid the output is not exactly what I am looking for. Can somebody please help me correct my Jolt Spec to get the exact transformation I am looking for? I have really tried cracking my brain at this and would really appreciate this last bit of help.

So currently I have that looks like this:

```
{
  "Hdr": {
    "DataSupplier": "BANK19000001",
    "FeedType": "Reuse",
    "SchemaVersion": "05.00",
    "SeqNo": "1",
    "DateProduced": "2019-09-30T11:44:12Z",
    "RecordCount": 1
  },
  "Data": [
    {
      "IM_SubmitterID": "BANK19000001",
      "IM_ParticipantID": "BANK19000001",
      "IM_AsOfDateTime": "2019-09-30T11:44:12Z",
      "IM_RepCpCodeType": "LEI",
      "CP_RepCp": "549300LW9VUUMJV5HC31",
      "CO_ActionType": "Normal",
      "CP_EntResponsibleForRep": "549300LW9VUUMJV5HC31",
      "LN_EventDate": "2019-09-30",
      "Clltrl": [
        {
          "CO_TypeOfCollComponent": "SECU",
          "CO_IdOfASecUsedAsColl": "FR0000131104",
          "RU_ValueOfReusedColl": "1000000",
          "RU_EstimatedReuseOfColl": "500000",
          "RU_ReusedCollCcy": "EUR"
        },
        {
          "CO_TypeOfCollComponent": "SECU",
          "CO_IdOfASecUsedAsColl": "FR0000131105",
          "RU_ValueOfReusedColl": "2000000",
          "RU_EstimatedReuseOfColl": "400000",
          "RU_ReusedCollCcy": "EUR"
        },
        {
          "CO_TypeOfCollComponent": "SECU",
          "CO_IdOfASecUsedAsColl": "FR0000131106",
          "RU_ValueOfReusedColl": "1500000",
          "RU_EstimatedReuseOfColl": "1000000",
          "RU_ReusedCollCcy": "EUR"
        },
        {
          "CO_TypeOfCollComponent": "CASH",
          "RU_ReinvestmentRate": "1.003",
          "RU_TypeOfReinvestedCashInvstmnt": "MMFT",
          "RU_ReinvestedCashAmt": "150000000",
          "RU_ReinvestedCashCcy": "USD"
        },
        {
          "CO_TypeOfCollComponent": "CASH",
          "RU_ReinvestmentRate": "0.05",
          "RU_TypeOfReinvestedCashInvstmnt": "REPM",
          "RU_ReinvestedCashAmt": "200000000",
          "RU_ReinvestedCashCcy": "EUR"
        }
      ],
      "FndngSrce": [
        {
          "RU_FundingSources": "OTHR",
          "RU_MarketValueOfTheFundingSources": "12000000",
          "RU_FundingSourcesCcy": "USD"
        },
        {
          "RU_FundingSources": "BSHS",
          "RU_MarketValueOfTheFundingSources": "150000000",
          "RU_FundingSourcesCcy": "EUR"
        }
      ],
      "UsrDfnd": {
        "IM_UserDefined1": "Test Data"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the current Jolt Specs I have currently written so far (Edited):

```
    [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Hdr": {
        "*": "header.&"
      },
      "Data": {
        "*": {
          "*": "data.&",
          "Clltrl": {
            "*": {
              "*": "data.&"
            },
            "UsrDfnd": {
              "*": "data.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And the output after the transformation:

```
{
  "header" : {
    "DataSupplier" : "BANK19000001",
    "FeedType" : "Reuse",
    "SchemaVersion" : "05.00",
    "SeqNo" : "1",
    "DateProduced" : "2019-09-30T11:44:12Z",
    "RecordCount" : 1
  },
  "body" : {
    "CO_TypeOfCollComponent" : [ "SECU", "SECU", "SECU", "CASH", "CASH" ],
    "CO_IdOfASecUsedAsColl" : [ "FR0000131104", "FR0000131105", "FR0000131106" ],
    "RU_ValueOfReusedColl" : [ "1000000", "2000000", "1500000" ],
    "RU_EstimatedReuseOfColl" : [ "500000", "400000", "1000000" ],
    "RU_ReusedCollCcy" : [ "EUR", "EUR", "EUR" ],
    "RU_ReinvestmentRate" : [ "1.003", "0.05" ],
    "RU_TypeOfReinvestedCashInvstmnt" : [ "MMFT", "REPM" ],
    "RU_ReinvestedCashAmt" : [ "150000000", "200000000" ],
    "RU_ReinvestedCashCcy" : [ "USD", "EUR" ],
    "RU_FundingSources" : [ "OTHR", "BSHS" ],
    "RU_MarketValueOfTheFundingSources" : [ "12000000", "150000000" ],
    "RU_FundingSourcesCcy" : [ "USD", "EUR" ],
    "Test Data" : null
  }
}
```

This is really closed to the desired result. However, it is missing some data from the "Data" section of the input. I have literally tried every possible combination and have tried searching for an answer online, but to no avail.

Desired Json output:

```
{
  "header" : {
    "DataSupplier" : "BANK19000001",
    "FeedType" : "Reuse",
    "SchemaVersion" : "05.00",
    "SeqNo" : "1",
    "DateProduced" : "2019-09-30T11:44:12Z",
    "RecordCount" : 1
  },
  "body" : {
    "IM_SubmitterID" : "BANK19000001",
    "IM_ParticipantID" : "BANK19000001",
    "IM_AsOfDateTime" : "2019-09-30T11:44:12Z",
    "IM_RepCpCodeType" : "LEI",
    "CP_RepCp" : "549300LW9VUUMJV5HC31",
    "CO_ActionType" : "Normal",
    "CP_EntResponsibleForRep" : "549300LW9VUUMJV5HC31",
    "LN_EventDate" : "2019-09-30",
    "CO_TypeOfCollComponent" : [ "SECU", "SECU", "SECU", "CASH", "CASH" ],
    "CO_IdOfASecUsedAsColl" : [ "FR0000131104", "FR0000131105", "FR0000131106" ],
    "RU_ValueOfReusedColl" : [ "1000000", "2000000", "1500000" ],
    "RU_EstimatedReuseOfColl" : [ "500000", "400000", "1000000" ],
    "RU_ReusedCollCcy" : [ "EUR", "EUR", "EUR" ],
    "RU_ReinvestmentRate" : [ "1.003", "0.05" ],
    "RU_TypeOfReinvestedCashInvstmnt" : [ "MMFT", "REPM" ],
    "RU_ReinvestedCashAmt" : [ "150000000", "200000000" ],
    "RU_ReinvestedCashCcy" : [ "USD", "EUR" ],
    "RU_FundingSources" : [ "OTHR", "BSHS" ],
    "RU_MarketValueOfTheFundingSources" : [ "12000000", "150000000" ],
    "RU_FundingSourcesCcy" : [ "USD", "EUR" ],
    "IM_UserDefined1" : "Test Data"
  }
}
```

Can somebody please help me modify my Jolt Specs to achieve the desired result.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't supply softcopy of the input data, I wasn't able to test with your own data.  However, I made up the following logical equivalent.  Imagine we have as input:

```
{
  "hdr": {
    "a": "a"
  },
  "dta": {
    "b": "b",
    "c": [
      {
        "d": "d1",
        "e": "e1"
      },
      {
        "d": "d2",
        "e": "e2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and what we want as output is:

```
{
  "header" : {
    "a" : "a"
  },
  "data" : {
    "b" : "b",
    "d" : [ "d1", "d2" ],
    "e" : [ "e1", "e2" ]
  }
}
```

then the following can be used as a Jolt Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "hdr": {
        "*": "header.&"
      },
      "dta": {
        "*": "data.&",
        "c": {
          "*": {
            "*": "data.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thank you for your example. Using that as a reference point I was able to updated my specs. However, I am unable to get the desired result. I believe the error may lie in this part 
      "Data": {
        "*": {
          "*": "data.&",
          "Clltrl": {
            "*": {
              "*": "data.&",
              "FndngSrce": {
                "*": {
                  "*": "data.&",
                  "UsrDfnd": {
                    "*": "data.&" 

Again, it is almost there, but I am unable to get "FndngSrce" and "UsrDfnd" on the same level as the rest of the data.

Comment: If you could update the question or otherwise post a link to your best so far JOLT spec that would be great.  I sat down this evening to have a go at the puzzle but the comment post above would mean that I have to do a lot of work to get the spec right.  When posting, please try and make it as easy as possible for any responder to assist with tests etc.

Comment: Here is an example JSON JOLT spec that seems to work:

https://pastebin.com/aJ0ev1vj